# How to assign values in constructor using rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, constructor

The main objective is to get the sum of the given array, the array can contain any number of elements so i am using rest operator to accept the array, but I am facing issue i.e the return value is always 0, I am not getting how to assign the arguments(PASSED AS REST) to the constructor. Below is the piece of code and the answer am getting, I would be thankful if anyone helps me to understand this.

```
class Polygon{
    constructor(...lengths){
       this.lengths = lengths //I am not getting how to asssign here
        
    }
    perimeter(...lengths){
        var sum = 0
         for(const arg of lengths)
         {
             sum += arg
         }
         return sum
     }
   
}


let triangle = new Polygon([3, 4, 5]);

// Print the perimeter
console.log(triangle.perimeter());
```

Output

```
PS D:\Javascript(instfold)\basicfiles\basic> node practice.js
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to use `...` in constructor parameters. If you are passing values separated with comma, then only you need to use `...`.

Secondly, `perimeter` If you are calling the `perimeter` without arguments then how could you use `...lengths` in `perimeter` parameters.

Thirdly, If you are creating an instance variable in the constructor using `this.lengths` then either you should use `this.lengths` in `for..of` loop or you should pass the argument to perimeter and collect it using rest and then use `lengths`

**Below code with `rest` parameters when passing values separted with comma.**

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(...lengths) {
    this.lengths = lengths; //I am not getting how to asssign here
  }
  perimeter() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const arg of this.lengths) {
      sum += arg;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

let triangle = new Polygon(3, 4, 5);

// Print the perimeter
console.log(triangle.perimeter());
```

Below code is with array argument and not using `rest` parameter

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(lengths) {
    this.lengths = lengths; //I am not getting how to asssign here
  }
  perimeter() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const arg of this.lengths) {
      sum += arg;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

let triangle = new Polygon([3, 4, 5]);

// Print the perimeter
console.log(triangle.perimeter());
```

**UPDATED with arbitrary length array**

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(lengths) {
    this.lengths = lengths; //I am not getting how to asssign here
  }
  perimeter() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const arg of this.lengths) {
      sum += arg;
    }
    return sum;
  }
}

let triangle = new Polygon([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);

// Print the perimeter
console.log(triangle.perimeter());
```

**TIP:** Below snippet is what I would write If I were you

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(dimensionArray) {
    this.dimensionArray = dimensionArray;
  }
  perimeter() {
    return this.dimensionArray.reduce((total, dimension) => total + dimension, 0);
  }
}

let triangle = new Polygon([3, 4, 5]);

// Print the perimeter
console.log(triangle.perimeter());
```

Comment: How will it differ if the elements in the array is [3,4,5,6] ? I tried to use rest operator because the total number of elements in the array is not known. So by using rest we can get every element(this was my idea)!

Comment: Doesn't matter the length of the array. You just need to pass the array and use `for..of` loop to get element sequence-wise.

Comment: @AravindaKS see the updated answer and snippet

Comment: Yeah, the concept is cleared now, Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: **TIP: ** It would be better to use meaningfull array names so that they are easy to understand e.g `lengthsArray` or just use `array`

Comment: check last snippet again @AravindaKS

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I always name every variable and array with names that can be understandable(I follow coding standards of styling), But this problem was given in some coding challenge website, so we have to use the same otherwise it won't pass the test case.